# Does MySQL support secure credit transactions?

Tags: mysql

I've been engaged to design and produce a website for my local grocer. They want to have purchases made through the website and I envisage that they will be keeping customer data.  But what I would really like to know is can I securely store credit card details in a MySQL database? Could you please describe the process, generally, for achieving this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no, you can store data securely via encryption and/or hashing in MySQL. MySQL is just a relational database, you can use such a relational database to store securely customer data, and you can use it to store it insecurely.

Anyway, doing this thing right is hard, really hard, be it with MySQL or with any other database.

I recommend using a third party service to handle the transactions, there are various companies on this space competing with the big ones (Amazon, PayPal, Google.)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is a database, not an order processing software. It is your, programmer's task to make your MySQL transactions code secure. So the answer is both yes and no.